# Python - Análise de Dados - Error na leitura de arquivo em formato xlsx

Tags: python, pandas

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando realizar a leitura de um arquivo xlsx no python via pandas, porém retorna erros; como se o arquivo não existisse (porém ele está na mesma pasta que o script em python). Tentei passar o caminho do arquivo e mesmo assim não funcionou. Segue o código abaixo. Estou utilizando o jupyter lab, anteriormente tentei o vscode porém retornava o mesmo erro...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

simulacao_projeto = pd.read_xlsx('simul.xlsx')
```

Seguinte erro que retorna é:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-1e337f1a57f3> in <module>
----> 1 simulacao_projeto = pd.read_xlsx('simul.xlsx')

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_xlsx'
```

Comment: Tem certeza que está executando o código que colocou? Pela mensagem de erro parece que executou `simulacao_projeto = pd._xlsx`.

Comment: Estou executando simulacao_projeto = pd.read_xlsx('')

Comment: Ah, a mensagem de erro estava errada. Já verificou a documentação para certificar se esse método existe? Não deveria ser `read_excel`? Pelo menos no [documentação da versão 0.25.2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/io.html) não há o método `read_xlsx`

Comment: Já tentei `read_excel` porém retorna um erro ainda maior. O arquivo que quero ler é o simul.xlsx, eu já coloquei ele dentro da mesma pasta, já tentei passar o diretório que ele se encontra, mas continua a retornando o mesmo erro...

Comment: A planilha não tem nada de diferente, apenas quatro colunas contendo dados de alguns sensores de um projeto que desenvolvi...

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema. Inicialmente para ler um arquivo, precisa-se ser inserido o diretório onde o mesmo se encontra (como ele estava tudo na mesma pasta, não precisei colocar). No caso de `simulacao_projeto = pd.read_xlsx('simul.xlsx')` podemos notar nesta linha de código, que precisei inserir o `r` antes de `simul.xlsx` (indicando que era um diretório) e mudar o `pd.read.xlsx` para `pd.read_excel` ficando agora `simul = pd.read_excel(r"simul.xlsx")`. Com isso, meu código parou de exibir erros e executou como esperado!

Comment: o `r` aí é desnecessário e não indica que é um diretório. Ele é um prefixo de string que existe no Python para informar que é uma *raw string*, ou string crua, que não escapará os caracteres na presença da barra invertida. O problema era somente chamar a função, como já havíamos indicado.

Comment: A função foi chamada inúmeras vezes de diversas formas, assistir várias videos no youtube e pesquisei em várias locais e nada dava certo. Ontem fui tentar novamente por um video no youtube que justamente colocava apenas esse `r` antes de inserir o nome do arquivo que o mesmo almejava ler e por incrível que pareça funcionou. Segue o vídeo do camarada [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQUYpJvMgn8).

Answer (score 0):

A função a ser usada é "[read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)", pois "read_xlsx" não existe no pandas:

Comment: eu entendo, sei que não 'existe'. Porém só houve a necessidade de inserir o `r` no caminho que mencionei acima. Abraços!